# NSIS Installer and Visual Studio 2015 community Edition

Tags: visual-studio, nsis

We had a developer leave and I'm trying to make myself familiar with his deployment process. The past developer would create two versions of his install. One was a update and the other was an install.

I see in the src code he has a .NSIS folder with the scripts already written.

How do I use those scripts to build our NSIS installers? I've looked at Visual Installer, but I don't see how to implement those scripts for the build process.
Edit
"He" is the old developer that left. I'm trying to push out a new build of the ACInstall.exe and ACPatch.exe. I've looked at NSIS online tutorials and they mostly talk about creating the script. I have the script but I'm not familiar with how to use it. ie what tool to run to build the ACInstall.exe.

Here are the files he created and how the project's explorer looks.
[image: Icons]

[image: projectfolder]

Comment: What are you trying to do? What isn't working? What have you tried so far? Who's "he"?

Comment: Jesse "He" is the old developer that left. I'm trying to push out a new build of the ACInstall.exe and ACPatch.exe. I've looked at NSIS online tutorials and they mostly talk about creating the script. I have the script but I'm not familiar with how to use it. ie what tool to run to build the ACInstall.exe.

Comment: Have you installed nullsoft installer itself? http://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/ and read the wiki? http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.nsi files are plain text files and the NSIS compiler (makensis.exe) will produce a .exe from a .nsi.

You need to [install NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download) to get the NSIS compiler, Visual Installer just provides Visual Studio integration (syntax highlighting etc).

Comment: Following Jesse and your comments I've installed NSIS, but when I run the command line makensis.exe Installer.nsi the system can't find the .exe to run. I can run NSIS and compile the script no problems and test the installer. Is it another way to build the script?

Comment: So compiling the nsi script will build the installer. That's the part I was missing. I was looking for a build option outside the compiler. I think..

Answer (score 0):

Anders, you can use a number of NSIS script editors, not sure if this is your requirement. You can use HM NIS, I think it's the better free, but it's a bit 'ole' (more than 8 years for sure). I hope this answer can be of help to anybody looking for the same answer.